# How to get values inside _JsonDocumentSnapshot?

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

Flutter Streambuilder code below runs without error and returns (screenshot at bottom):

```
ID: AzFdOO9WsFaFbTxTQsuo
Data: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
```

### How do I get to the values inside the _JsonDocumentSnapshot and display them in the Text() widget?

For instance, there's a string field called "name", but I can't figure out how to get to it.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("groceries")
                .doc(widget.docId)
                .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, streamSnapshot) {
            if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Text("Loading");
            } else if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
                return Text("ID: ${widget.docId}\n"
                            "Data: ${streamSnapshot.data}");
            } else {
                return const Text("No Data");
            }
        }
    )
```

[image: Screenshot of _JsonDocumentSnapshot]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following `Stream`, return an object with a type of `DocumentSnapshot` :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("groceries").doc(widget.docId).snapshots();
```

and that type contains the document snapshot, and also contains more additional information about the document.

so in order to get the JSON `Map<String, dynamic>` which represents the data of the Firestore document, you need to call `data()` on the result of the `snapshot.data()`, so you need to try the following:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("groceries")
            .doc(widget.docId)
            .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
        if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
        } else if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
            return Text("ID: ${widget.docId}\n"
                        "Data: ${streamSnapshot.data.data()}"); // added data()
        } else {
            return const Text("No Data");
        }
    }
)
```

now it should show the `Map<String, dynamic>` object which contains your document data in the `Text` widget.

hope this helps.

Comment: Looks so easy, but when I use ```streamSnapshot.data.data()``` I get a squiggly error: "The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Object'."  Any ideas?

Comment: yes, I totally didn't noticied that, you didn(t specify the type of the snapshot on any where in the StreamBuilder, wait I will edit the code

Comment: try now the new StreamBuilder code, I specified the snapshot type that it should return from the stream

Comment: That did it!  I never would've thought of that.  For the record, I had to use ```streamSnapshot.data?.data()```, but this really really helped.  I'll mark it the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you, I recommend checking over this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration it can help.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example `streamSnapshot.data` is an `Object` or a `dynamic` type variable.

To access the json value of your data, you have to specify the key corresponding to your value.

`streamSnapshot.data['banana']`